# Can change Array<T> to IntArray, FloatArray, CharArray ...ECT, automatically using Generic in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, functional-programming

I am a beginner of Kotlin and I am studying this book.

**Functional Kotlin: Extend your OOP skills and implement Functional techniques in Kotlin and Arrow**

This book contains the following codes:

```
sealed class FunList<out T> {
  object Nil: FunList<Nothing>()
  data class Cons<out T>(val head: T, val tail: FunList<T>): FunList<T>
}

fun initListOf(vararg numbers: Int): FunList<Int> {
  return if (numbers.isEmpty()) {
    Nil
  } else {
    Cons(numbers.first(), initListOf(*numbers.drop(1).toTypedArray().toIntArray()))
  }
}
```

This is an example of building a data structure. This is an example of building a data structure. I wondered if I could use a generic of the type that goes into `FunList` in `initListOf` function. For example:

```
fun <T> initListOf(vararg items: T): FunList<T> = if (items.isEmpty()) {
  Nil
} else {
  Cons(items.first(), initListOf(*items.drop(1).toTypedArray())) // error
}
```

But the code didn't work.
The reason is that if I put the same type of factor into the varag parameter, it was converted to `IntArray`, `FloatArray`, `LongArray`, and `CharArray`, which was recognized as a different type from `TypedArray`(`Array<T>`).

How do I get them to automatically create the same type of FunList when I put in the same type of variable?
It's just academic curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varags and typed arrays are a bit more finnicky to work with than Lists when using them in a generic way, because they have reified types (no type erasure). So you can overload your function with a version that takes a List parameter instead:

```
fun <T> initListOf(items: List<T>): FunList<T> = if (items.isEmpty()) {
    Nil
} else {
    Cons(items.first(), initListOf(items.drop(1)))
}

fun <T> initListOf(vararg items: T) = initListOf(items.toList())
```

Comment: As an aside, recursively converting a list this way looks like a very heavy operation with the potential for a stack overflow if the list is long.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look very pretty but you can do the following

```
fun <T> initListOf(items: Array<T>): FunList<T> = when {
    items.isEmpty() -> FunList.Nil
    items.size == 1 -> {
        FunList.Cons(items.first(), initListOf(items.copyOf(0) as Array<T>))
    }
    else -> {
        FunList.Cons(items.first(), initListOf(items.copyOfRange(1, items.size)))
    }
}
```

and then you can call it as

```
initListOf(arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5))
```